# Alternative to SimpleGrantedAuthority

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I recently started a springboot course where the course lead uses Spring Security GrantedAuthority interface.  I couldn't resolve GrantedAuthority's path And after reading more I saw that it's depricated and SimpleGrantedAuthority should now be used.  For some reason I also can't resolve the path to SimpleGrantedAuthority.  under security.core.authority all I have is Mapping.  Any idea what I can use instead?

```
The code of the course I started:

package com.bookstore.domain.security;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 123123L;

    private final String authority;

    public Authority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show me where it's says that it is`depricated`: [SimpleGrantedAuthority](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/authority/SimpleGrantedAuthority.html)

Comment: I think you're confusing GrantedAuthority with GrantedAuthorityImpl which was indeed deprecated https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/authority/GrantedAuthorityImpl.html . In the latest milestone you can see that GrantedAuthority and SimpleGrantedAuthority both still exist in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.M5/api/

Comment: @Aidan Moriarty  Any idea why i'm unable to resolve that?  I can only see mapping under authority...

Comment: What version of spring security are you depending on?

Comment: @Aidan Moriarty  spring boot starter (spring security 4.3.2-release)

Comment: There doesn't seem to have been a 4.3.2 release so I assume you mean 4.2.3, the last 4.x release ... you can see GrantedAuthority right here - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.2.3.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core . I think you need to carefully check your setup again, something is not right.

Comment: @Aidan Moriarty Yes 4.2.3.  I can see that the jar files are downloaded under project properties/java build path/libraries...  Any idea what else I should/can check?

Comment: Sounds like some oddity within your build environment at this point, which is very hard to diagnose at distance, sorry. Just assume its not that the class is deprecated anyway and focus on your build setup

Comment: Take a maven update. alt+F5